# Migrating a Postgres Table in Rails to Ensure a combination of column values is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In postgres you can do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  a integer,
  b integer,
  c integer,
  UNIQUE (a, c)
);
```

Is there anyway to specify that a combination of values on two columns must be unique in a rails postgres migration?

Answer (score 1):

i think this is

```
 add_index(:example, [:a, :c], unique: true)
```